# Can someone explain this "for" loop in python?

Tags: python, windows, list, spyder

I don't understand the meaning of this for loop, specifically the range arguments:

```python
for element in range(len(text1)-1,-1,-1):
    print(text1[element])
```

Comment: It prints `text1` in reverse.

Comment: Please add the code in the question and not in the comments.

Comment: #stayIndoors - stay indoors                        
def cap_space(txt):
    new_char=""
    for char in txt :
        if char.upper()== char:
            new_char += " " + char.lower()
 
        else:
            new_char += char
    return new_char
 
print(cap_space("stayIndoors"))

Comment: Why javascript tag ?

Answer (score 1):

The loop will `print` the element of the list `text1` at position `element`, but the for loop will make it print starting first from the last element of your list `text1`.
The syntax of the range is the following: `range(start,stop,step)`. The reason why the loop starts at `len(text1)-1` is because list in python are indexed not starting from `1` but from `0`. So if your list has `n` elements, it will be indexed from 0 to `n-1`.

I suggest you try to change the values used in `range` to understand what is happening.

Comment: You could even add a `print(element)` to check what index is being called on the list to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above says it all. But I can add that making the second arguments of range `-2` or `-3` and so on, will make your loop goes multiple times. So once it's done printing all the elements of your list, it will redo the same operation as many times you specified.